# Code reuse for 'all objects of a type are equal' pattern

Tags: java, equals, code-reuse, boilerplate

I have a number of classes that all override their equals and hashCode methods to look like this:

```
final class MyClass {
  public void statelessMethod() {
    // ...
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof MyClass;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return MyClass.class.hashCode();
  }
}
```

The idea being that while the class has no state that ever changes `new MyClass().equals(new MyClass())` should always be true.

What I'm looking for is some code pattern or utility class that I can write (or reuse) that will remove as much of the boilerplate as I can.

*Background*

I'm using this pattern for defining Guice modules so that if more than one module depends on UtilModule (for example) I don't end up getting errors caused by multiple bindings of the same type.

*Extra Background*

This pattern was duplicated from the Guice Servlets InternalServletModule which uses it to allow you to specify multiple ServletModule modules in your injector configuration without duplicating the bindings that are provided as part of that class.

**Example of real use to answer some of the comments**

```
final class UtilModule extends AbstractModule {
  public void configure() {
    // bindings and things
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof UtilModule;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return UtilModule.class.hashCode();
  }
}
```

**Example of more than one module depending on UtilModule (from comments)**

```
class Module1 extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(SomeClass.class).to(SomeClassImpl.class);
    install(new UtilModule()); // needed by SomeClassImpl
  }
}

class Module2 extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(MyService.class).in(Singleton.class);
    install(new UtilModule()); // needed by MyService
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
        new Module1(),
        new Module2());
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you even need to be able to create instances of this class? Why not make the constructor `private` and all methods `static`?

Comment: You could do it in a parent type (and make the methods final) but this all smells a hack.

Comment: You have a method that returns no value and has no state?

Comment: I edited the question with a more complex example to clear up why static won't work

Comment: How about using `this.getClass()` in a parent class's implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()`? These methods would never need to be overwritten because `this.getClass()` always refers to the *actual* type of the current object.

Comment: Could you give an example of "if more than one module depends upon UtilModule"? I wonder if this is something that could be solved by just declaring separate modules and using @Provides methods...

Comment: @Charlie - I updated the question with an example of UtilModule multiple-use

Comment: @Matt - Thanks. I see 2 options.. One is have your module1 and module2 explicitly take a UtilModule. That way you can pass the same module to all. (And being the same object, default hashCode and equals will work. Two is to not install UtilModule, instead provide it separately to your createInjector, and pass the responsibility of proper bindings to the assembler.

Comment: @Charlie - Thanks, neither of those two options seems very nice to me, option one would require a lot of modules being passed in the constructors of other modules. Option two is what I used to have before I found this patterns and you end up in a huge run-error-fix-run cycle as you try to figure out all the missing modules that you should be installing. The pattern I found with the equals works fine for me for this reuse, I would just like some help reducing the boilerplate

Comment: @Matt - Ah, makes sense thanks. I'm relatively new to Guice so such experiences help a bunch. I'm curious if you've looked at/ what you think of Dagger http://square.github.com/dagger/

Answer (score 0):

Your classes could all extend a common base class which implements equals and hashCode. In that case you have to replace the references to `MyClass` with `this.getClass()`.

Also, `instanceof` is not what you want, because it will also return true when obj is of a class which extends the current class. That would not just be unlikely to be what you want, it would also violate the contract of equals, because when you compare an instance of a base class with an instance of an extending class, it would matter on which one you call the equals method (derived is instanceof base, but base isn't instanceof derived).

The implementation in your base class would look like that:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   this.getClass().equals(obj.getClass())
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return this.getClass().hashCode();
}
```

On an unrelated note: When the objects have no internal state, why not use the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: Using the singleton pattern is a possible option, it kind of goes against the patterns used for the rest of the classes I've written and could cause some confusion as to where to get a particular instance from, i.e. some classes are created via new and some via singleton patterns but both are used in the same place.

Comment: Sub-classing could work, I would have to be careful to avoid pitfalls related to multiple inheritance though. I guess having it there for use in simple hierarchies would be useful for the simple case and you can always fall back to writing it yourself in the more complex case

Comment: _Also, instanceof is not what you want, because it will also return true when obj is of a class which extends the current class_ - I think it works in this case because my class is final

Comment: @Matt - *"... I would have to be careful to avoid pitfalls related to multiple inheritance though"* ... Java doesn't allow multiple inheritence.

Comment: "... Java doesn't allow multiple inheritence" - That's what I mean, there is no multiple inheritance so I would have to be careful to include this base-class in the correct place in my class hierarchy to achieve the best reuse while also keeping the best flexibility, I.E. not forcing this rule down users throats who don't want or need it but do want some of the other functionality associated with some class in the hierarchy

Comment: You said you have *a number of classes* - are you sure that they are *all* final? And that they all *will ever be* final?

Comment: I can never be sure about the future but I know that it is the case now for all cases where the equals and hashCode are implemented in this way

Comment: @Philipp - I've also just realised that the parent-class approach would not work for my main use-case, which is that each class should only exist once. That is if you put a load of them into a Set then iterate over them calling the 'doSomething' method then each implementation of that 'doSomething' method should only be called once. So with that in mind I would have to make all sub-classes final anyway to avoid this pitfall